# Can the subject of “mettre quelque chose à profit” be an inanimate object?

Tags: constructions

Can the subject of the verb mettre in “mettre à profit quelque chose” be an inanimate object?

I’m struggling to find the answer to my question. I have checked [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Profit) and still I have no success.

If you are also having difficulty finding the answer, then please could any french natives provide a very **simple** example where the subject is inanimate so that I know it’s possible.

Comment: I guess you found the usual examples like 'son temps', 'ses compétences', 'ses connaissances'... Do you mean like in "J'ai mis mon ordinateur à profit" for instance?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example can't be the answer to this question; when trying to determine for what choice of words a construction is idiomatic, a large number of examples has to be considered, and you can't generalize from the mere existence of one example.

The subject of “mettre qch à profit” can be an inanimate object, but apparently, only to the extent that this object is a person-like entity or  a processus, or akin to a processus.

- BSFI (financial organisation), direction Serbe, la France, la Toscane, l'administration
- nature, doctrine, mode de règlement, philosophie, jeu de l'amour propre, sagesse, présence d'esprit, l'habileté, l'éloquence, le génie, l'intelligence

The examples shown below have been extracted from the first 100 entries in this  [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG4dvXkNvuAhVj4uAKHQ22CXUQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1) and in [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

*person-like entities*

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_g1QAQAAMAAJ&q=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&dq=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJnebhkNvuAhUT5uAKHasoBHQQ6AEwD3oECDgQAg)) le BSIF a rapidement diffusé des comptabilité d'assurance et au Comité consultatif des préavis et mis à profit ses pouvoirs d'établissement de IFRS

([ref;](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yg4HAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&dq=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJnebhkNvuAhUT5uAKHasoBHQQ6AEwInoECFAQAg)) La direction serbe a mis à profit la situation tendue en Kosove pour faire pression sur les organes d'Etat au niveau de la Fédération et des autres républiques afin d'appliquer plus facilement sa stratégie dans toute la Yougoslavie

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=exFbAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA65&dq=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJnebhkNvuAhUT5uAKHasoBHQQ6AEwTXoECCUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mis%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) Voilà comment elle [la France] a mis à profit ses quarante ans de paix ;

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=SeIJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA225&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwPXoECD4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false))  la Toscane met à profit les minerais de l'ile d'Elbe ;

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XRSZCXJkDwQC&pg=PA122&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwWnoECCkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) et l'administration des haras les met à profit

*processus and akin to one*

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uJpVAAAAYAAJ&q=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&dq=%22mis+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJnebhkNvuAhUT5uAKHasoBHQQ6AEwJnoECFYQAg)) Le procédé a posé des problèmes de filtration par suite de la texture des précipités obtenus et a mis à profit des séparations par centrifugation. d) Extraction liquide-liquide. Dans certains cas, l'analyse du zirconium a mis à profit l'extraction ...

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ng0_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA403&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwKHoECFcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) qui s'y refuse , la nature rectifie l'erreur , et met à profit le même remède pour exciter un émonctoire plus disposé à s'ouvrir : c'est ainsi que l'opium, administré comme sudorifique, provoque quelquefois l'action du système urinaire

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uAuAUJSrSO0C&pg=PA147&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwLnoECDoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) sa Doctrine des causes actives, qui embrasse tous les faits et met à profit tous ...

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oQRCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA355&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwMHoECF4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) il [ce mode de règlement] améliore votre règlement, et met à profit l'heureuse idée de l'honorable général.

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KHTvSZduzUcC&pg=PA89&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwNXoECGEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) la philosophie puise, dans un commerce intime avec elle, des inspirations puissantes; elle met à profit ses saintes images

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Jx9ZUlPSGqwC&pg=PA118&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwOXoECEsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) Le Désintéressement passe pour un jeu de l'amour propre, qui met à profit le renoncement apparent à de petites choses pour arriver plus surement à une plus grande utilité

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3LV6VF2hesUC&pg=PA72&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwOnoECDIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false))  parce qu'il manquoit de cette sagesse qui met à profit toutes les bonnes qualités qu'on peut avoir

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VXYPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PP127&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwPnoECDcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false))  cette présence d'esprit qui met à profit les circonstances

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DglMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwSnoECB8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) L'habileté au contraire, met à profit les fautes des autres

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PD9CAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwTHoECCMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) Tantôt, rassemblant tous ses moyens, toutes ses ressources, elle [l'éloquence] les dirige avec préméditation vers un but, les combine et les dispose pour produire un effet commun ; elle met à profit les passions humaines, les échauffe et les remue

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EsUWAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR2&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwTnoECCQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false)) le génie du prince met à profit les résultats obtenus

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rDCGKxH0BIsC&pg=PA4&dq=%22met+%C3%A0+profit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFx7S8l9vuAhWE5OAKHUppAvUQ6AEwUXoECCgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22met%20%C3%A0%20profit%22&f=false))  la suprême intelligence met à profit les antipathies, et la lutte régulière des principes opposés devient pour elle un moyen d'entretenir la vie dans l'univers